# Get key value pair from Map

Tags: java, arrays, json, hashmap

I have this code to retrieve map's key value pair:

```
countries = BeneficiaryJSONParser.parseCountriesFeed(result);
for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry: countries.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
}
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
data : [{234=United Arab Emirates, 103=India, 210=Sri Lanka, 235=United Kingdom, 216=Switzerland, 200=Singapore, 76=France}]
status : 200
code : 1
```

I want to get data as an array with key and value. Because, I want to put those key-value pairs in,

```
final MyData items[] = new MyData[3];
items[0] = new MyData( "234","United Arab Emirates" );
items[1] = new MyData( "103","India" );
items[2] = new MyData( "210","Sri Lanka" );
.
.
.
```

Comment: And what JSON library are you using? Why don't you deserialize it into a POJO?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map

Comment: @itrollin98 : actually the question is not to iterate all entries in `Map`. It's something I need to iterate `data` (described in output)

Answer (score 4):

You just need to convert each entry into a MyData:

```
List<MyData> data = new ArrayList<> ();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> e: countries.entrySet()) {
  data.add(new MyData(e.getKey(), String.valueOf(e.getValue());
}

final MyData[] items = data.toArray(new MyData[0]);
```

Or using streams:

```
final MyData[] items = countries.entrySet().stream()
                        .map(e -> new MyData(e.getKey(), String.valueOf(e.getValue()))
                        .toArray(MyData[]::new);
```

Comment: It's giving me `[data, status, code]` when I tried with `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(items));` I need the country list within `data` object

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want that is not covered by my suggested solution.